# When is a static loop called?

Tags: java, for-loop, static

In a Java class at what point does a static loop get called?
and how often is it referenced?
im only familiar with calling a method, and

I have seen it on this truly excellent answer to Euler Q14, been doing a java a year but this the first time ive seen this here:

[stackoverflowquestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195400/too-long-runtime-of-euler-project-14-in-java)

```
static {
for (int i = 10; i < cache.length; i *= 2)
    collatzNum(i - 1);
        }
```

Comment: It is not a "static loop", but a static block which just happens to contain a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called static initialization block. You can used it to initialize static variables. This block will be called when the class is loaded.

FYI

> A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they
>   can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees
>   that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they
>   appear in the source code

For more details, check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: Thank you, i had no idea classes could be initialised this way

Answer (score 1):

The static blocks are called in the sequence in which they are declared, and they are get called when the class is loaded by your jvm ---ClassLoader